# MySql query to check occurence which happened on each day between two dates?

Tags: mysql

This is the MYSQL table schema :

```
+---------------+---------------------+
| username      | last_activity_time  |
+---------------+---------------------+
| raphael       | 2011-11-28 23:16:34 |
| donatello     | 2011-11-28 23:17:36 |
| michaelengelo | 2011-11-29 10:08:28 |
| raphael       | 2011-11-29 11:11:33 |
| leonardo      | 2011-11-29 11:12:30 |
+---------------+---------------------+
```

A NEW record with username and last_activity_time is inserted for each activity.

Query requirement :

**Select all users who did some activity DAILY between two dates say 2011-11-20 and 2011-11-30 ( both included )**

"IN" query does not seem to be an option as it works for any value in the IN array, not ALL.

Comment: just to know, is your last_activity_time updated at each new activity ? If yes, how do you want to know if this activity was just a daily one ?

Comment: @tsabz no it is not updated,just a new insert happens with a username and datetime. Edited the question as well to make this clear.

Comment: Check my answer then, it will normally do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT username, COUNT(*) AS nbr_day
FROM (
    SELECT username, DATE(last_activity_time) AS last_activity_date
    FROM my_table
    WHERE ( last_activity_time >= @date1 )
    AND ( last_activity_time < DATE_ADD( @date2, INTERVAL 1 DAY) )
    GROUP BY username, last_activity_date
) AS sub
GROUP BY username
HAVING ( COUNT(*) = 1 + DATEDIFF(@date2, @date1) )
```

This query counts the number of different days for each username. And then retain only those for which this number is equal to the number of days between the two dates.

The expression "DATE_ADD( @date2, INTERVAL 1 DAY)" represents the date just after @date2. It it used rather than @date2 because "last_activity_time" contains date and also time.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `BETWEEN` to get data between two dates.

```
SELECT username, mast_activity_time FROM table 
WHERE last_activity_time BETWEEN "2011-11-20 00:00:00" AND "2011-11-30 23:59:59"
GROUP BY username, last_activity_time HAVING COUNT(last_activity_time) = 1
```

Note that this query will work only if you insert a new entry for each new activity. If you just update the entry in your table, you won't be able to retrieve what you want as your previous data will be erased from the table.

To understand better, check [HAVING](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)

Comment: this is not correct. I need users who did activity DAILY. this query will give me users who did activity ANYTIME between the two dates.

Comment: it does not seem to do the needful.
This query will select record even if it has activity on a single day say 2011-11-29 , and not in 2011-11-28. I want records which have activity on ALL dates 2011-11-20, 2011-11-21....2011-11-29,2011-11-30

Comment: Then also group by last_activity_time

Comment: that does not work as well. That query also gives users with activity on one or two days in the set, which is incorrect.It should be ALL days.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont any advanced query, you can use BETWEEN. (Link: [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between))

and with that you can do something like this:

```
SELECT username,last_activity_time FROM users WHERE last_activity_time BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2';
```

Comment: this is not correct. I need users who did activity DAILY. this query will give me users who did activity ANYTIME between the two dates.

Comment: then you need do add another table with activity history, you cant get that information with just these 2 columns. This is because when you update last_activity_time, the old data is lost

Comment: It depends if with each new activity, he update the entry for a user, or just insert a new one.

Comment: @trembon , thanks for pointing out the point. However, the data is not updated, a new record is inserted everytime an activity is done. I will edit the question too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT count(distinct date(last_activity_date)),username 
FROM users 
WHERE last_activity_date between start_Date and end_Date 
group by user_id;
```

If the count is equal to date difference,
they have logged in at least once per day in between the two days